# Ansible - 'when' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to figure out how to "remove" the warning message `[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: ps_nodes`, by fixing the root cause. The root cause for me is that when we do Linux machine creation we will have the ps_nodes hosts empty. So, I was trying to add the `block:` + `when: (os_type|capitalize) == "Windows"`, to assure that Play to only execute when os_type is a Windows creation.

How can I achieve that? Because, what I'm trying is to use the when condiction, but looks like it's not possible, and I'm not sure what to search anymore.

Code example:

```
    - name: "Start handling of vm specific delete scripts for Windows machines"
      block:
        hosts: ps_nodes
        any_errors_fatal: false
        gather_facts: false
        vars:
          private_ip_1: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['_private_ip_1']|default('') }}"
          scripts: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['scripts'] }}"
          sh_script_dir: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['sh_script_dir'] }}"
          cred_base_hst: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['cred_base_hst'] }}"
          cred_base_gst: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['cred_base_gst'] }}"
          newline: "\n"

        tasks:
        - import_tasks: roles/script/tasks/callWindowsScripts.yml
          when: action == 'delete'
      when: (os_type|capitalize) == "Windows"
```

Error using 'when' for a Play:

```
ERROR! 'when' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '/opt/projectX/playbooks/create_vm.yml': line 265, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

##############################################################################
- name: \"Start handling of vm specific delete scripts for Windows machines\"
  ^ here
```

Comment: You have a group, `ps_nodes`, that has hosts with different OS types, such as RHEL and Windoze?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the indentation. Use 'and':

```
  - name: "Start handling of vm specific delete scripts for Windows machines"
      block:
        hosts: ps_nodes
        any_errors_fatal: false
        gather_facts: false
        vars:
          private_ip_1: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['_private_ip_1']|default('') }}"
          scripts: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['scripts'] }}"
          sh_script_dir: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['sh_script_dir'] }}"
          cred_base_hst: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['cred_base_hst'] }}"
          cred_base_gst: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['cred_base_gst'] }}"
          newline: "\n"

        tasks:
        - import_tasks: roles/script/tasks/callWindowsScripts.yml
          when: action == 'delete' and (os_type|capitalize) == "Windows"
```

Got it,

What if you use a host that exists, like localhost, check the number of hosts in ps_nodes and delegate_to them?

Something like this:

```
hosts: localhost
vars:
tasks:
 - import_tasks: roles/script/tasks/callWindowsScripts.yml
   delegate_to: ps_nodes
   when: {{ ps_nodes | length > 0}}
```

Comment: I don't want to check for the task, I really want to check the full Play, so that is the reason to have the when in the line below, because I'm not applying it to task, but to the full Play, if I put the when condiction in the task, I will not get rid of the "[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: ps_nodes"

Answer (score 1):

Same issue and fixed by "indent":

```yaml
- hosts: test
  roles:
    - role: test
      vars:
        k: 1
      when: "'dbg' in ansible_run_tags"
```